# Returning multiple arrays using JSON in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to return 2 arrays along with a third variable by encoding all of them into a JSON array.
I want access to all the keys of both the arrays and also the third variable. I have had a hard time trying to do so. All i was able to do was this, without any success..

Help required. Is there a way I can copy the whole json_encoded data['states'] into a JS array?

onlineStudents.php

```
<?php
require_once 'myfunctions.php';
$query="Select * from online_students";
$result=  queryMysql($query);
$data["total"]=mysql_num_rows($result)-1;
$query="Select distinct state from online_students";
$result=queryMysql($query);
while($row=  mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $query2="select * from online_students where state='$row[state]'";
    $result2=queryMysql($query2);
    $data["states"]=mysql_num_rows($result2);
}
$query="Select distinct college from online_students";
$result=  queryMysql($query);
while($row=  mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $query2="Select * from online_students where college='$row[college]'";
    $result2=queryMysql($query2);
    $data["colleges"]=mysql_num_rows($result2);
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

myfunctions.php

```
function queryMysql($query)
{
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    return $result;
}
```

myfunctions.js

```
function peoples()
{
 $.getJSON("onlineStudents.php",function(data){
        $("#chat_head_number").html(": "+data['total']);
        $("#chat_states_number").html(data['states']);  //i want the whole array data[states] instead of a single value
        $("#chat_college_number").html(data['colleges']);
        });
}
```

Comment: Your JSON sending and reading seems fine. You might have to put `{}` around `$row[state]` like `{$row[state]}` in your SQL queries. Did you check that those were replaced correctly?

Comment: off topic: please note that the `mysql_xxx()` functions in PHP are deprecated and their use is discouraged. You should consider switching to a newer database API such as the PDO library.

Comment: Are you trying to return a single JSON object with all of the data in it? It would be helpful if we could see what you're table schemas look like. If you use a couple of `JOIN` statements, you could do it all in a single step, `mysql_fetch_array` and then return the JSON. It is also recommended that you use the **JSON_PRETTY_PRINT** option when encoding.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast - but the query runs fine even without the braces.

Comment: @Spudley - I was unaware of that. Thank you for the update.